# Exception during the serialization - Type with data contract name is not expected

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

I have this classes:

```
[DataContract]
class ClassA
{
    [DataMember]
    public Object Value; // and this can be of ClassB or some primitive type.
    ...
}

[DataContract]
class ClassB : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, ClassA>>
{
    [DataMember]
    private Dictionary<String, ClassA> dictionary;
    ...
}
```

but getting this exception when serialization take place:

> Type 'MyNamespace.ClassA' with data contract name
>   'ClassA:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace' is not
>   expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known
>   types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them to the list of known types passed to
>   DataContractSerializer.

I feel that I should use `KnownType` attribute, but I can't figure out how, because I am not owning `IEnumerable<T>`.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(int))]
// Same way add here all the types that you are using in your class A.
class ClassA
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Value;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why would `[KnownType(typeof(int))]` help when? `System.Int32` is always a known type.

Comment: I'm afraid that you both are right,partially. Indeed, `KnownType` is missing there. I'll put details in an answer.

Answer (score 7):

I've finally get it right. The solution is quite simple, `Value` from first class is of type `Object`, and the serializer have to know which types will be boxed into that `Object`.

So `ClassA` should be declared as:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ClassA)]
[KnownType(typeof(ClassB)]
class ClassA
{
    [DataMember]
    public Object Value; // ClassA or ClassB or some primitive type.
    ...
}
```

This document [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/04/21/understanding-known-types.aspx) really helped clarifying what is `KnownType`.

UPDATE: Because the upper link seems not working anymore, here is a link to an archived webpage:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160304050721/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/04/21/understanding-known-types.aspx

Comment: Sorry to everyone who was trying to help, because at first I wrote `int Value`, but in fact that was an `Object`, and that was the most important part in my question.

Comment: The link is dead. It can be simpipied as `[DataContract, KnowType(typeof(...))]`.